# Broadcasting User-Activity over Twitter

Tags: feature-request, twitter

**Example:** Jonathan answered "Page generation from PHP Class" http://bit.ly/RIPog

---

Many sites broadcast (opt-in of course) your activity over your twitter-line, letting your friends/followers know what you're up to, discover content that you find, and participate in events/projects that you're participating in.

Has it been considered by the SO Team to implement a Twitter-broadcasting system to send out activity from users to their followers? This would be great for getting SO more traffic, and would help some of us keep our followers happy even when SO commands more time than Twitter now days.

Comment: Im for this, Even some sort of checkbox, Like post this to Twitter, Just as same as: Email me on Updates

Comment: Question on SO for developing such a script: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311383/script-to-publish-my-so-qs-and-as-on-my-twitter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you *really* want this, use http://twitterfeed.com/ http://rsstotwitter.com/ and your ["user feed"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/130154)

Also related, there is a third-party [stackalert twitter bot](http://twitter.com/stackalert)

Personally I dislike this idea, Twitter is already noisy enough without encouraging lots of auto-generated posts.. http://twitter.com/isnotrss

Comment: I don't understand these charges against twitter being too noisy - twitter is an opt-in community. If somebody is too noisy, don't follow them. Seems simple enough.

Comment: Great suggestions here though - I'll probably go with one of them. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this has been requested before. Personally I think it has problems: for regular users it would be *far* too much noise to be useful. Better for users to occasionally tweet a question/answer they've found particularly interesting, IMO.

RSS feeds for users can serve the same sort of purpose, if you really want. (Are there RSS feed to Twitter feed converters? Sounds like an obvious thing to do.)

Comment: As an opt-in, how would this be a problem?

Comment: I could see it driving loads of traffic back to SO.

Comment: It would be a problem by being not terribly useful in reality (IMO) but still taking time to implement.

Comment: Of course when we've got Wave integration, it's just a matter of creating a label with the right search :)

Comment: It's more marketing, and would be useful for SO I think. Many of us programmers have programmers following. SO would be broadcasted in yet another medium as THE place to get solutions. I could see some users broadcasting their RSS feeds too, if SO really didn't want to bother with this.

Comment: If you answer questions regularly, it would get very boring for people following you. If you answer questions rarely, you can easily tweet that explicitly for particularly good ones.

Comment: @Jon: your assumption here seems to be that most users currently have interesting, uncluttered Twitter feeds and this feature would produce a large number of anomalies. I'm not sure this is actually the case...

Comment: I don't think you guys need to really base your opinion on whether or not you would like to follow *my* feed. I follow feeds that get updated almost every other minute, and I enjoy it. Remove yourself from the equation. I don't mean that in an insensitive way either.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this has been implemented in one form for stackexchange: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ and http://twitter.com/chiphackers

Answer (score 0):

I've requested it before, and it's been declined.  Everyone appears to believe the best option is an RSS<-->Twitter service of one kind or another.

When I did that, it wasn't done well (the RSS isn't optimized for Twitter, so titles are too long, etc).

A specific service that did this just for SO would be nice if it also took into account special actions on SO:

- I just got the Organizer badge on Stack Overflow
- My answer to "80 char question title" was selected as the best answer, etc.

This would be more interesting to me than a new tweet for every single question and answer. Maybe alerts only once they've reached certain 'trigger' vote levels (5 votes, 25 votes, 100 votes, selected as answer, gone below 0 votes, etc), alerts for badges, etc.

Comment: is there any particular reason you're using a signature block? We don't typically allow that. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed-on-stackoverflow

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed-on-stackoverflow/5040#5040

Comment: There's a comment raised on that very answer as to why do you think it's a problem people would judge the **content** of the post over the author.

Comment: I didn't address that comment specifically because I believed a careful reading of the answer shows the comment is already dealt with.  I've made that more explicit since it's obvious that isn't the case.

Comment: So you don't see any avatars or signature blocks with badges and rep counts then?

Comment: I'm more than happy to address your comments at the correct location for that discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed-on-stackoverflow/5040#5040 - please consider using this comment area for discussion on the topic "Broadcasting User-Activity over Twitter"