# Is adding a signature considered spamming?

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Should ‘Hi’, ‘thanks’ and taglines and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)
>   [What is the policy on signatures and links in answers for Stack Overflow questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28416/what-is-the-policy-on-signatures-and-links-in-answers-for-stack-overflow-question)

I would like to add a signature to all my answers?

I would consider this fair use when I spend time answering questions. 
The signature would of course contain a link and obviously, yes, it is for improving the page rank.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: Um, you do realize links in answers are nofollowed, right?

Answer (score 12):

Signatures are not allowed on Stack Overflow.

Put whatever information you want on your user page -- that's what it is there for! -- but cluttering up questions and answers with redundant information is not a valid use of the system.

see:

- [What is the policy on signatures and links in answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28416/what-is-the-policy-on-signatures-and-links-in-answers-for-so-questions)
- [Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed-on-stackoverflow)

Comment: You need the rep or why haven't you closed this as dupe?