# Review action on signature

Tags: discussion, review, flags, suggested-edits

I recently reviewed an answer containing a signature with a link to a company the user was working for. I took took this as spam and suggested flagging it as such, which was then rejected. After this I suggested removing the link, which preserves the rest of the answer.

My question is therefore: "When reviewing an answer containing links not related to the answer, what is the recommended action?"

I realize this might be considered opinion-based, but surely there should be a recommended approach across stack exchange communities?

This is related to [policy on signatures and links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28416/what-is-the-policy-on-signatures-and-links-in-answers) and a supposed duplicate "[is adding a signature considered spamming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38570/is-adding-a-signature-considered-spamming?lq=1)", but while it is clear that signatures and links are not desired, there is no suggestion as to how to treat it.

Comment: Any fluff that's not related to the answer should be removed. It's odd that you couldn't deduce the answer from the first post you linked.

Comment: @IͶΔ I agree that "fluff" is undesired, but I suppose my question was more whether one should edit the answer or if some other action is more appropriate.

Comment: calling it spam is over the top. Save that for the handbags and streaming tv and love spell posts. If a promotional link can just be edited out, leaving a useful post, that's what you should do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I see a signature, email, or website link (if it looks to be promotional in nature), I edit them out, with a comment like:

> Signature etc removed as per Help instruction

I use the following statement in the [Help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) as my justification for doing that:

> **Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.**
>
> Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card,
>   which links directly back to your user page. If you use an additional
>   signature or tagline, it will be removed to reduce noise in the
>   questions and answers.
>
> Your user page belongs to you — fill it with information about your
>   interests, links to stuff you’ve worked on, or whatever else you like!