# How to view comment revision history

Tags: support, comments

Since comments can be modified, is there a way to view a sort of revision history (with the modifications applied to the comments) like you do on questions/answers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not for us mere mortals.

Only [Stack Exchange staff members](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344161/152859) can see the revision history of comments, but that doesn't include edits made during the edit window (so only changes by moderators are kept in the revision history, which makes it practically useless for normal users)

Related: [Let moderators see the original, unedited version of comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277193/245360)

Comment: Moderators can't see revision history either; that's an employee-only power.

Comment: "Moderators can see the revision history of comments" - as far as I know it's not correct, and it's even clearly mentioned in the question you linked to. Also, there is no such thing "grace period" for comment edits. The answer is not totally wrong since the first sentence is correct, but the rest is not.

Comment: @ShadowWizard There is a five-minute "grace period" in which non-mods can edit their own comments. (Ironically, you've made use of that in the comment you just made, and I'm making use of it right now in this comment.)

Comment: Indeed, the 5 minutes from first posting the comment until it is locked. All changes are not kept now.

Comment: @rand but it's not "grace period". It can be called "edit window". Edit grace period is reserved, as far as I know, for post edits, which within the grace period (5 minutes) won't create new revision. If we could edit comments any time, then the term would make sense, but we can't. Proof that it's different is the fact that we can see that comments were edited: we can't see any indication whatsoever that a post was edited during grace period.