# Add edit suggestions and edit history on comments

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comment-edits

I've seen lots of comments that are in desperate need of editing, mostly for grammar. Currently, there is no mechanism for users to edit comments, except the owner (and maybe moderators, I'm not sure). Also there is no revision history for edits made by the owner of the comment.

#### Feature request:

Allow users to suggest edits on comments *that can only be approved or rejected by the comments owners*, and provide revision history for comments.

Comment: I don’t want anyone else editing my comments. And mods don’t need more work arbitrating petty disputes. The risk and pain simply ain’t worth the tiny price of having misspellings in comments. Sorry, -1.

Comment: @DanBron I've changed my suggestion so that the comment owners decide what edits are applied.

Comment: Thanks. That *is* a massive improvement. But I’m sorry, I still don’t want others have the ability to give me more work reviewing their comments. For the “occasional” spat that crops up in the comments here on SE, there is a >100% chance it will be abused. My downvote isn’t directed at you, to be clear, I just don’t want this.

Comment: Editing comments and comment revision history are [both available for mods](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278241/270345).

Comment: @DanBron I understand your point, however I personally think it would be worth it to allow suggested edits on comments.

Comment: Moderators aside, comments are only editable by their owners for up to five minutes. After that, they are static. And comments are *assumed* to be transitory. They can be and often are deleted at any time. Being able to edit them more significantly goes against their intended purpose.

Answer (score 16):

Questions and answers allow wiki-style editing so they can be corrected and improved over time as a way to keep them relevant and canonical. But comments are not **meant** to become a meaningful, *lasting* part of the original post, by definition. They are meant only to ask for clarification or to help folks improve, edit, or add to the original post.

Asking folks to circle back to fix up a bit of text which should be short-lived by definition is not consistent with the intended purpose of comments. Comments are not meant to be kept relevant through vigilant editing. If you can improve upon something stated in a comment, you should add your voice to the collaboration… or go in and fix the issue being discussed by editing the original post itself.