# Can moderators redact revisions of a comment?

Tags: support, comments, revision-redaction

A user on SOja found that his sensitive information was post as a comment. I, as a moderator, edited that comment to remove that sensitive information, but is this enough?

[Moderators can view the edit history of a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240827/341401), and I confirmed that the information is remained in a revision. Can I redact that revision of a comment? If so, how to do so?

Comment: You can't... The revision history is *only* visible to mods... Non-mods can see a comment has been edited (and how many times) but not what any past revisions were... so it's a fairly moot point.

Comment: ...and as per the moderator agreement, they are forbidden from disclosing that info or using it beyond functions necessary to carry out their duties as a moderator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by Jon Clements and Sonic the Inclusive Hedgehog: it's not possible, and not likely to be implemented either.

> Non-mods can see a comment has been edited (and how many times) but not what any past revisions were. The revision history [itself] is *only* visible to mods...

> ...and as per the moderator agreement, they are forbidden from disclosing that info or using it beyond functions necessary to carry out their duties as a moderator.