# How to ask a moderator to check if someone is not downvoting by revenge?

Tags: support

I ask meta exchange to run a script to see who downvoted me, as I suspect the same person, because I had many downvotes all at the same time, after an argument with someone.

I'd like to know if I can ask it publicly, as I think maybe some moderators seems to know some users and won't make the check.

Comment: Moderators cannot see who has voted for whom, and wouldn't be allowed to tell you even if they could.

Comment: I heard the opposite from some people, it seems that some moderators did that for some people. So, is it normal to have serial downvoters for a revenge? I don't think so.

Comment: Oh, and who told you that a moderator told them who voted on their posts?  Revenge downvotes aren't abnormal, no, they're quite common in fact.

Comment: @Servy I'm a diamond mod on SQA.se and yes, we can analyze a profile to detect certain types of serial downvoting. Without getting into specifics, it is quite effective.

Comment: @Quidam What site is this a problem on? Your best bet is to use the meta on that site to get in touch with the moderators to run an analysis on your profile.

Comment: @corsiKa And yet you still can't see who voted for whom, as the votes are anonymized.

Comment: @Servy Again that is not accurate. If someone's behavior was statistically offensive enough to warrant action, I know which account I need to take action against.

Comment: Please moderators, remove this question.

Comment: I really really really really really really fed up to receive regularly downvotes for this question that is very very very very old. So please please please, remove it.

Comment: I go on receiveing negative downvote REMOVE THIS QUESTION!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

No one can check who voted on what post, let alone why.

Only the user that casted the vote knows which post they casted it on and why. The system within Stack Exchange though does see if anyone has been the target of mass voting and will reverse the votes if that is the case. But no, no one can tell you who voted on what. And definitely, no one can tell you what the voter's true intention was.

To clarify here, moderators can't see who voted, but they can see the *trends* within the voting. Two different things here.

Comment: This answer is not entirely accurate. Moderators do have the ability to detect abnormal voting patterns. If, for example, someone has serial downvoted you, there is a good chance that when a moderator runs a downvote analysis on your profile it will show the offender. If the offensive behavior pattern doesn't show up on the report, it probably wasn't sever enough to warrant any action (even if it was a douche move for the person to do...) - this is separate from the automated background scripts that detect mass serial downvoting.

Comment: @corsiKa this basically means we have been lied to for the last 6 to 8 years. Not nice. What else is a lie?

Comment: Well I think "being lied to" is a bit of a stretch. I don't remember exactly when it was implimented, but the team is constantly working hard to improve the quality of moderation tools. It could be the statement was accurate when they told you, and others with out of date information continued to propagate the inaccurate information.

Comment: It is good to know that we can now flag our posts and ask a mod to look into down votes. I assume the mods on the high traffic sites will be thankful for that.

Comment: your best bet would be to stop into chat and ask instead of flagging, personally

Comment: @rene - Eh. Moderators can't see downvotes. Not on posts. What they can see is *trends* between users. This is very different from what you seem to think is happening and is completely in line with everything you have been told in the past - that hasn't changed. No one has lied to you.

Comment: There's a bit of confusion here, @rene: moderators *cannot* see who has voted on individual posts (work-arounds for this are [considered bugs and fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42324/should-moderators-use-their-abilities-for-personal-reasons/42359#comment97965_42359)). It *is* possible for moderators to see when one user targets another, if the system determines there's a strong enough signal to show this information; moderators can thus take action in extremely blatant cases, and tend to forward all other complaints to employees (who can see everything if need-be).

Comment: ***If*** a user has cast an abnormal amount of votes at a specific user, mods can see the trend (it has to cross a threshold that we won't disclose in order for that to even be possible). So they can see the actions don't hold up to a lot of scrutiny, and then involve us (the team) who _can_ see all votes in the system as needed.

Comment: Also, it's generally okay for mods to _not_ involve us in clear cut cases of sock puppet voting rings, which they routinely break up by removing fake accounts - when it's really that obvious there's no need. The revenge patterns (in particular, those that realize there's something examining patterns and trying to evade it) are typically what get interesting (just clarifying that we don't always have to get involved, which my previous statement sort of suggests).

Comment: Ok, that clears things up for me. Thanks for chiming in.

Comment: My apologies if I contributed to the confusion. It seemed from my interpretation of the answer that moderators were unable to detect or take action against an offensive user, but rather that we were at the mercy of the automated script. As I reread it that might not have been the case. Absolutely, individual posts cannot be inspected by a moderator. Such a power would no doubt be abused and isn't necessary since an individual data point simply isn't actionable on its own anyway.

Comment: PLEASE stop downvoting this very very very old thread. Until when it will get downvoted? Until the end of the world? (I'm talking to downvoters who take fun to downvote old thread like this one)