# Primer on Moderator Capabilities and Best Practices?

Tags: discussion, support, moderator-abilities

I just passed the 10k rep mark on StackOverflow. I've been around the community long enough to have earned said reputation amount, so consider myself somewhat familiar with StackOverflow and how it operates. But I have to confess that these new moderator tools are somewhat lacking in documentation or policy on how best to use them. I've seen posts here on Meta from other moderators who are getting static for their (ab)use of these tools as well, and I don't want to go on repeating history.

My request, then, is for some kind of FAQ or other training device that details a bit more the new tools that are at my disposal. I'd also appreciate best practices for using them and continuing to be a valued member of the community with the new responsibilities I've been granted.

Comment: There is a difference between 10k abilities and moderator tools. Moderator tools are reserved for diamond mods.

Comment: This is a nice companion to [this question about Moderator powers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39405/moderator-accountability-request).

Comment: possible duplicate of ["You have gained power. Here's how to use it." kind of message.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15661/you-have-gained-power-heres-how-to-use-it-kind-of-message)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the moderation tools available to high-reputation users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4565/what-are-the-moderation-tools-available-to-high-reputation-users) (This is the FAQ entry you asked about.)

Comment: @Chacha - They are named like this in the FAQ - "10000: Delete closed questions, access to moderation tools".

Comment: Hmm, I may have misunderstood your question (and therefore misapplied [support] instead of [feature-request]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read through the [help center page on the privilege](/help/privileges/moderator-tools) and all the questions tagged with [10k-tools](/questions/tagged/10k-tools) here on Meta. That should give you a good sense of what to do, what not to do, and what issues exist with the Tools pages.

<sup>(Note: that tag is clickable.)</sup>

Comment: Can this be formalized somehow? My thought is that 10Kers who are shown this information will be better off than 10Kers who get burned for bad practices and then go hunting for this information...

Comment: @fbrereto: Agreed. You could suggest adding some kind of link to Meta from the [Tools Links Page](http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=links), since there is already a 'welcome to the club'-type message.

Answer (score 2):

From [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50069/why-are-we-deleting-instead-of-merging/50581#50581), I included *this* suggestion:

When I became a 10K user, I looked a the "tools" functions and said "okay, now what?" I heard through the grapevine that I could do some delete-post thing if I could figure it out. The more friction, the less people who participate.

#### SUGGESTION 1

At the very least, the "tools" link should bring 10K users to a specific "`10K Tools`" tab. Let 10K users know what they can do right there, all in one spot. The rest of the tabs and the dozens of links are cool, but they are eye candy which obscure the primary functionality. The functions under that tab should clearly define the responsibilities just acquired:

- [Closed questions eligible for deletion]
- [Recently deleted questions that can be re-opened]
- ... and whatever other functions you want 10K users to look at regularly.