# What is the name of the block after a post or comment that contains the username, gravatar, and reputation?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, user-interface, user-card

What is the name of the block after a post or comment that contains the username, gravatar, and reputation?

In the HTML it seems to be called "user-info" and contains "user-action-time", "user-gravatar32", and "user-details".

Is there a diagram naming the various elements on a SE page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We call it the "**user card**" most of the time.

An example [from the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq):

> *Can I use a signature or tagline?*
>
> Please don’t use signatures or taglines in your posts. Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard **user card**, which links directly back to your user page. Your user page belongs to you — fill it with information about your interests, links to stuff you’ve worked on, or whatever else you like!

Or [the badges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges):

> As you use Meta Stack Overflow to ask and answer questions, you’ll earn badges, which appear on your user page and in your **user card**.

Comment: Stack Exchange archaeology corner: Jeff referred to them as "user cards" as early as June 4, 2010, when he [added that term to each site's `/faq`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28416/what-is-the-policy-on-signatures-and-links-in-answers/52486#52486).

Comment: And it's now part of our glossary - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/40354/revisions

Answer (score 0):

How about:

> ### Post Signature

?

<sub>*(Shamelessly stolen from the html markup)*</sub>

Comment: Technically the block in question would be the "Post Signature Owner" by this method.