# Signature in question

Tags: discussion, questions, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are taglines/signatures disallowed on stackoverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed-on-stackoverflow)

I have a simple question - are links to personal sites allowed in people signatures in questions?

I have seen edits that removed those links and also [did it myself](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2286911/revisions), but is it explicitely stated anywhere that those links cannot be put in questions?

Comment: It's great if you love spam. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed-on-stackoverflow

Comment: You need to go back and fix that question, that user edited back his spam.

Comment: @random: done ;-)

Comment: Nice... just got a cleanup badge out of it.

Comment: WTF, @fre? "Hi there" and "thanks" is still in there. If you do a job, do it **right!**

Comment: @John: Chill you German. I just did a rollback. How else could I've got that cleanup badge ;-) But... as usual... your wish is my command... better now?

Comment: *sigh* @fre. What is this? A step by step instruction? What's wrong in "How to detect"? Do it **R.I.G.H.T!**