# Why cannot this post be taken as spam?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, spam, declined-flags

My flag got rejected by flagging as spam on this post:

*[What is a columnar database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133017/what-is-a-columnar-database/5692973#5692973)*

- It's not an answer, just a link to a [blogspot.com](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blogger_(service)) post
- The author has **recently joined** to post just that
- The author's web site in his profile is involved in his blogspot.com answer.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I flagged the exact same post a few hours ago. I had exactly the same thoughts as you. I'm a little disappointed we never reached a more general consensus in discussing [this spam candidate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87486/is-it-kind-of-spam-or-not), but rather focused on the specifics of that particular post.

Comment: Maybe related: [Usernames as Advertising or Spam?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61249/usernames-as-advertising-or-spam)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I destroyed the account, and here's my reasoning...

1. Unregistered account
2. No profile information except website
3. <= 3 answers
4. Answered an old question
5. Answered a question with an accepted answer
6. Answer contained no information other than a link to a blog

In my opinion, if you meet all of these requirements, you are a spammer.  It might be (and in this case was relatively) on topic, but not worthwhile enough to counteract the negative effect it has on the site.

On-topic spam is still spam.  The question becomes whether this user is capable of adding value or is *only interested in taking*.  We have plenty of users who pimp their own products (free or not) but who have registered, have filled in their account information (with disclaimers), and whose answers don't consist solely of a link to a blog post.

Comment: Glad to know that you also think "On-topic spam is still spam" :-) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing because it directly answered one of the asker's questions:

> Is there a trial version of a columnar database I can install to play around?

He should've mentioned that it's his own product, but other than that the answer seems valid

Comment: Valid, perhaps. Good quality? I believe link-only answers are generally frowned on, as they're useless as soon an external site goes down or re-organises. Plus here the circumstantial evidence is it just posted for an inbound link.