# Bounty given by Community - randomly?

Tags: support, bounties, community-user

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6737053/revisions) received bounty from Community (expired bounty probably)

My questions is - Why did this answer received bounty? Because it's most-voted ? What would happen in case of two questions with same votes? Would it be random ?

Comment: Just to note that taking _'I'm a Partner Engineer at Facebook.'_ out of the answer was not necessary. The user was declaring his affiliation with a body and this practice is encouraged if you're at all advocating (or somehow related to) external links.

Comment: Right, definitely don't remove affiliation disclosures. That was discussed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99202/when-answering-facebook-related-questions-should-i-disclose-that-i-work-at-facebo), specifically about our new guests who work at Facebook.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: about this question, I forgot to rollback it after I read it all "we've fixed...", he don't have to repeat that he's from FB. Profile is point for that information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer in question received the bounty because it was posted after the bounty was started and received a score of 2+, having the highest score amongst eligible answers.

If two answers are tied in score at the end of the bounty period, the oldest is awarded.

From [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work), under `What is automatic awarding?` (*Bolding mine*):

> Twenty-four hours after the end of the bounty period, if the bounty
>   starter has not manually awarded the bounty, an eligible answer can be
>   automatically awarded half the bounty amount. The criteria for an
>   answer to be eligible for automatic awarding are as follows:
>
> ```
> The answer must be given after the bounty was started
> The answer must have a score of at least +2
> ```
>
> If two or more eligible answers have the same score, the oldest answer
>   is awarded the bounty.
>
> **If no answers meet these criteria, the bounty ends without it being
>   awarded to any answer, and is not refunded to the bounty starter.**
>
> An accepted answer that does not meet the above criteria is still
>   ignored by the automatic-awarding system unless it is accepted during
>   the bounty period. An answer accepted during the bounty period will
>   automatically be awarded the full bounty.