# Stack Overflow username policy

Tags: discussion, support

I have looked at FAQ and tried googling for it but I am unable to find it. My question is what type of user names are allowed here. Actually, I want to create a Stack Overflow account with my software title as user name. Is this allowed here?

Comment: Why do you want to create a new SO account when you already have one?

Comment: @hims056 I want to create it for my product so that I can answer questions related to my software from that account.

Comment: You're free to use whatever name you'd like, as long as it's not overly offensive. And keep in mind that giving your account the name of your software will have some eagle eyed users taking a good look at your posts for spam. So better stay as far away from that as possible.

Comment: Have you seen [What are the rules governing display names and avatars?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99914/what-are-the-rules-governing-display-names-and-avatars)

Comment: Related: [Usernames as Advertising or Spam?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61249/usernames-as-advertising-or-spam)

Comment: @GeorgeCummins I was unable to find that page. Maybe because page title was not matching my search queries.

Comment: There was an answer here... Now it is deleted. Could anyone post an answer?

Comment: There are plenty of answers to the duplicate questions, and plenty of other questions that have discussed similar issues. Check the "Linked" and "Related" sidebars if you're still looking for more information.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't need more information. That was a good answer and shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: The author deleted it himself @VarunAgw. That's entirely up to him.