# Can I create a Stack Exchange Account as My Company Name?

Tags: support, display-names

According to terms of service of this site, can I create a account as my company name?

For example: assume that I have company / Business / Start-up called "ABCDEF".

Can I create a Stack Exchange account with "ABCDEF" as display name?

Answer (score 13):

Barring any legal considerations and rights to use that name, you can use a company name as your user name/identity. See [Usernames as advertising or spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100922/98786).

But keep in mind that our Terms of Service require that accounts be owned used by an individual (i.e. not a corporate entity), so folks can not create a *shared account* for use by their "organization".

Answer (score 3):

I've seen some companies doing this already, e.g. when they use Stack Overflow as part of their [product support system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/is-it-acceptable-to-use-stack-overflow-as-a-qa-for-a-specific-product).

From the [Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal), section 7:

> As a condition to using Services, Subscriber may be required to register with Stack Exchange and select a password and profile name.
> ...
> Subscriber may not (a) select or use as a profile name a name of another person with the intent to impersonate that person; or (b) use as a profile name a name subject to any rights of a person other than Subscriber without appropriate authorization.

(b) implies that if you *do* have the rights, it's no problem at all.

A related discussion can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61249/usernames-as-advertising-or-spam).