# Automatic signature

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Is it possible to define email signature in Stack Overflow, so I don't have to type "Thanks blah blah" every time I answer a question.

Comment: Nope. SO is a different kind of bird. We dont need the sigs!!

Comment: Why would you say "thanks" at the end of an answer?

Comment: I think SO should require you to make a comment when you vote a question down.  This is a good question, clear and helpful.  It should not have a down vote at all.  Thanks for asking it.

Comment: 15 downvotes :( I think I am losing all my votes here. :( :(

Answer (score 25):

Not only does this not exist, but you shouldn't be doing it manually either. See [Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed):

> In general, **taglines and signatures are strongly discouraged**, and are likely to be edited out. We don't want to clutter up the questions page with a lot of redundant signature blocks and taglines and so forth.
>
> Please use your built in profile, avatar, and username as your signature; that's what they are there for, and every post you make is already "signed" this way!

Answer (score 10):

Nope - one is built in for you at the end of each question/answer.