# Hello.. Thanks...not permitted

Tags: support, stack-overflow, etiquette

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should 'Hi', 'thanks' and taglines and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Is it aesthetically important and rule abiding not to start a question with HELLO, and ending it with a THANKS..USERNAME

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Also see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I see what you did there ^_^

Comment: No it's not important. Fact is that many people despise it for their own reasons so they remove it.