# Can we add a "No Thanks" part to the FAQ?

Tags: feature-request, faq-update-request

SO's getting a bit silly now. Almost every hour I'm editing tags and thanks out of titles.

If we're not going to have automatic warnings to users during question composition, can we at least add to the FAQ?

Perhaps:

> A "thank you", whilst polite, is
>   unnecessary noise. This is not a forum
>   or chat: it is a knowledge resource.
>   The question body should just contain
>   the question. Therefore, please do not
>   write "thanks" or "regards" at the
>   bottom of your post; if you do, they
>   are likely to be removed!

and:

> Please do not write tags in titles.
>   Adding tags like "**jQuery -** Why doesn't
>   this dialog open?" is redundant and
>   noisy, as we already have a
>   consistent, indexable tagging system.

I realise that some people think that this is just pedanticism, or that I care more than is appropriate about this. But it *is* frustrating.. and ultimately needless. I'm happy to keep editing posts for now, but it'd be helpful to have a FAQ entry to which to point offenders.

"Thanks" have already been covered by [some Meta posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91345/hello-thanks-not-permitted), though [the active ones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed) tend to talk about "signatures" and stop just short of discouraging "thank you"s.

Comment: I should note that I'm referring to [this FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), not the collection of posts tagged `faq`. I'm not quite sure which the `faq-update-request` tag is supposed to refer to.

Comment: +1 from me. Pseudotags in titles are my particular pet hate. :)

Comment: @Grace: Thanks; was debating that. :)

Answer (score 31):

About tags in titles, Jeff Atwood, in [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/howto-writing-good-titles/10651#10651), said:

> I think it is fine to duplicate the tags in the title, but only when they can be worked into the titles organically and conversationally.

It's not fine, if the tag is added to the title as in "jQuery - Why doesn't this dialog open?" or "[Drupal 6] What module should I use to create a feed from search results?" but it is fine to have a question title such as "What Drupal 6 module should I use to create a feed from search results?"

The FAQ should report a section about tags in the titles, but it should make clear when they are fine.

Comment: Completely agreed.

Answer (score 9):

This may or may not be appropriate, but I wanted to add this to the record before [the original conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626227/sleep-and-superclass-properties) (which was not enjoyed in the proper location, which would have been chat) gets moderated away.

The user I was talking to had repeatedly reverted my edit that removed a "Thank you." signature from his -2 question. Pretty much *all* of his 175 questions have tags and titles! (though I managed to edit the first page before getting bored)

The following conversation ensued regarding this topic:

> **Me** Also, why did you add your tags and thanks back in? They are redundant
>   and frowned-upon. I didn't remove them
>   for fun.
>
> **[Francisc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383148/francisc)**
>   I'm sorry Tomalak, I do not understand
>   what you are saying. Only thing I got
>   was you not liking that I said "Thank
>   you." which I always do.
>
> **Me** SO is neither a forum nor a chat: it is a knowledge resource;
>   signatures and thanks are redundant.
>   All that should be in a question post
>   is the question. Please stop reverting
>   my edits.
>
> **Francisc** Dear Tomalak, the point of the question is not to explain how
>   serialize works. If you have an
>   answer, write it, if you don't, don't.
>   Also, there are no rules saying that I
>   cannot say Thank you. out of courtesy
>   (you do know what that is I hope). It
>   is not a signature. This being said,
>   please top editing my question for no
>   reason. As guidelines indicate: fix
>   grammatical or spelling errors,
>   clarify meaning without changing it,
>   correct minor mistakes, add related
>   resources or links, always respect the
>   original author. Goodbye.
>
> **Me** [This proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97860/can-we-add-a-no-thanks-part-to-the-faq), requesting that the already-well-known
>   conventions that I have described to
>   you be added to the Stack Overflow
>   FAQ, may be of interest to you. Also
>   [this section](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing) of the FAQ, which
>   reads "if you are not comfortable with
>   the idea of your contributions being
>   collaboratively edited by other
>   trusted users, this may not be the
>   site for you."
>
> **Francisc** Those are not rules. Sorry. As you said, it is a proposal.
>
> **Me** Yes, a proposal to add to some documentation the *already-well-known
>   conventions*. Conventions are not
>   rules, but conventions are
>   conventions, and a good member of the
>   community follows them. A good member
>   of the community certainly does not
>   stubbornly insist on reverting edits
>   that follow this convention, over and
>   over again.
>
> **Francisc** Which you just wrote... haha.
>
> **Me** Yes, I wrote it a few hours ago because I'm getting fed up of having
>   to deal with nonsense like this. It
>   seems like common sense to me. You
>   should notice that the proposal
>   references other posts, where people
>   ([including 144k meta rep moderator
>   Jeff Attwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989)) indicate that they
>   also would like "thanks" to go away.
>
> **Francisc** Tomalak, I like to say "Thank you." because if you got to
>   that point, you read all that I had
>   wrote. It's perfectly normal and
>   polite. I have been doing this in all
>   my question here and anywhere else. I
>   can understand pertinent edits and so
>   on, but this is purely subjective, I
>   pasted the valid reasons for editing
>   in my comment above. I'm not sure what
>   else there is to talk about.
>
> **Francisc** What seems like common sense to you doesn't mean it's a rule.
>   Again, stick to the rules. Edit
>   mistakes and clarify, don't rephrase
>   because you don't like how it looks.
>   How much does one line of text (which
>   is also polite to write) change in
>   terms of readability? Nothing.
>
> **Me** Yes, I can see you've been doing it on all of your posts. I
>   started editing them out but even I
>   got bored. There are no valid reasons;
>   you merely said "but it's polite",
>   ignoring both my counter-advice and
>   the established etiquette on this
>   *knowledge resource* website. There is
>   nothing else to talk about as long as
>   you continue to blindly ignore it.
>   Cheers.
>
> **Francisc** `fix grammatical or spelling errors, clarify meaning
>   without changing it, correct minor
>   mistakes, add related resources or
>   links, always respect the original
>   author`
>
> **Me** Also, I don't see why you think it's so damned polite. It's not as if
>   you're giving anything up by writing
>   "thank you". It's not as if it's
>   unusual that you're asking for help,
>   given the nature of the website. It's
>   merely a reflex action, not an actual
>   symbol of gratitude. An appropriate
>   symbol of gratitude would be to
>   contribute back into the community by
>   voting, answering questions, and
>   following established community
>   etiquette... not by writing two
>   arbitrary and redundant words at the
>   bottom of every single question,
>   adding needless noise.
>
> **Me** You're also demonstrating, by quoting that passage over and over
>   again, a lack of understanding of the
>   distinction between hard-and-fast
>   rules and etiquette. What would be
>   polite, is for you to follow the
>   established etiquette that I have told
>   you about. What would also be polite
>   is for me to end this conversation
>   right here... which I shall now do.

Am I way off base here? Am I missing something huge?

For me, it keeps coming back to "SO is *not* a message board", and my programmer's instinct is telling me to hold the line, to fight the fight, to keep that "question" field in the database full of only one thing: the question.

It seems really obvious to me, but it's clear that either I'm missing something or some people just *don't get it*.

Comment: Flag for moderator attention.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: I did.

Comment: I would venture to suggest that the repeated rollbacks and the comment war were much more noisy than the "Thank you".

Comment: @mmyers: Yes, they were, but that does not change the content of the argument in the slightest. There's a principle to uphold here.

Comment: Why don't you cite this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: @Ladybug: I did, after the conversation had supposedly ended. :) At the risk of [giving Jeff too much credibility](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97283/dont-remove-the-part-of-my-comment), that he shares my opinion was too good not to point out.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but shouldn't this be part of your question?

Comment: @Chris: Probably. I felt that, ultimately, it was too long to add as an addendum. I'm still not quite clear on the metaquette.

Comment: I'd side with mmyers here. Don't ever get into a rollback war with the original author *on your own*. If there is really a problem, bring it up here first and get some heavy weights on your side :) I *totally* agree that pre-emptive thanks are extraneous *and* meaningless.

Comment: My own policy is to remove thanks from posts **only if there is something else in the post which needs editing**.

Comment: And I knew I had support for that from somewhere, http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/

Comment: @TRiG: Fortunately, in such cases, there _almost always_ is. IME.

Answer (score -8):

@LightnessRacesInOrbit, no offence, but I must respectfully disagree with you. You made some very good points [in your argument](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97860/can-we-add-a-no-thanks-part-to-the-faq/97912#97912), particularly about rules vs. conventions, and the other person definitely took it too far by constantly reverting your edits (I would never do that), but I've always hated this aspect of Stack Overflow, and here's why:

1. "Thank you" is a basic human courtesy. It separates us from animals and mindless robots that only care about having "a [perfectly-clean] knowledge resource". Once again, no offence intended to you or anyone else with your viewpoint.
2. It takes me a good hour or so to formulate what I hope to be a clear, concise question that will help others in the future as well as myself. I don't have the time to contribute any more than that (i.e. answering or editing), so putting a bit more effort into my questions is how I try to make up for that. As such, I feel as though anyone who does the same by answering my question well, deserves MTIA.
3. It's not even that noisy...it's **nine extra characters** for Pete's sake! Or eight in my case, since I usually say "MTIA :-)".

I doubt I'm the only person who feels this way among the moderators (obviously I'm not one of you, but I mean that a few of you probably share my viewpoint...or at least I hope so).

**Update 17 hours later**: I just watched [Jeff's Opening Keynote at Iterate 2018](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vrKTSg5gWN4) and I **finally** get it. I wish it weren't the case so I could ramble on about how much this incredible man has changed my life for the better, but that would obviously be wrong for this site. I apologise, but it's the last time I'll say that here. Or "the words that shall never be spoken (for all the right reasons)".

Comment: I don't see *Thank you* anywhere on Wikipedia. We're/want to be closer to that content model then the frivolous forum style with its social media aspects. We know you're all thankful, we know you're all courteous, we and all our future visitors don't need to be reminded of that fact every frigging post.

Comment: @Rene with all due respect, Wikipedia is not a Q&A website. They do not have a pool of users who dedicate their free time to answering questions, voting and closing posts,  daily, which are posted by the *public* or by other community members. It can be annoying to read "Thanks in advance" when the author has not made one single effort but in those cases where effort has been invested, a "thanks" feels like a normal spontaneous response.

Comment: @Mari-LouA TIL that Wikipedia isn't collaboratively edited. Thanks in advance for informing me.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A the answerer is just one person, whereas those who come to read the question and answer later can be thousands more. That's who the no thanks rule is for, as it is just noise to them.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I knew there had to be at least one of you! I won't say the infamous words that you know I want to, but I hope my intention is clear ;-)

Comment: Luckily your only 9 years late to the party.

Comment: LMAO @Luuklag, I know, right?? I thought about the appropriateness of answering here vs. creating a new question, but I felt as though this is more of an answer than a question.

Comment: In any case you are bot bringing anything new to the table, as this has been discussed (and shot down) time and time again.

Comment: You can put "Thank you" in comments.

Comment: Different forms of communication have different forms. We are not writing letters to each other on a Q&A site (it should be thought of as [Socratic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socratic_method)). A question is posed on behalf of many others that may have the same question (now or in the future). It is not a helpdesk (though there most definitely is a need for that, especially for beginners - here is a business opportunity for this company, or more likely, a startup). People in chat places will get pretty annoyed if you use salutations.

Comment: @PMort Yes as I said in my edit I realise that now. And I definitely agree that there should be a helpdesk. Or at least better effort to keep the FAQs and Help Center up to date.