# Is it OK to edit a user's post because you don't like their writing voice?

Tags: discussion, edits

I just stumbled upon [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1092832/revisions#spacer-a761b009-caf7-4481-9362-c8e68530e381). [raven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4228/raven) rewrote a user's use of the word "grok" and left the comment:

> people just don't 'grok' how stupid they sound when they say 'grok'. it has to stop

Grok is a [widely used word](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1_____enUS441US441&aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=grok) (especially in geek circles; eg. Jeff himself at the [bottom of this blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/welcome-valued-associate-josh-heyer/)) and it's included in [several dictionaries](http://onelook.com/?w=grok).

Is it acceptable to rewrite someone's post just because you don't approve of their writing voice?

Comment: Grok is a widely used word [citation-needed].

Comment: @Dennis: Click the link.

Comment: @JacquesCousteau: Just because a word appears in a dictionary, it's not necessarily a widely used word. Especially for non-native English speakers, even if they're otherwise good at it, **grok** means a trip to Google to understand the meaning of the post.

Comment: @Dennis: The first link was the 6.5 billion hits on Google, which is nearly as many hits as "non-native" (which you used in your sentence).     If we edit according to the metric "easy for non-native speakers", we'd replace all long or tricky or potentially obscure words with shorter/simpler ones. Is that really what we should be doing? I looked at a few of your posts and saw you used the words "shenanigans". Should I edit that into something friendlier to non-native speakers? How about your use of "heuristics", which gets about as many Google hits and is in as many dictionaries as "Grok"?

Comment: @Dennis: The same may be true of many uncommon English words (or more complicated sentence structures). Maybe we should convert SO to use Simplified English only? I don't think a quick trip to the dictionary is a huge burden here, especially since the overall pluggandisp can be glorked from context.

Comment: Grok is a made-up word, and it's US only. Substituting it in order to clarify the meaning of an answer is perfectly fine in my opinion. @JacquesCousteau: There's a **huge** gap between Simplified English and not using obscure words like *grok*.

Comment: @Mud: If you (or anybody else) wants to edit my posts to clarify their meaning, you're welcome to do so. I sometimes have a lot of trouble expressing myself. I do believe, however, that more people are familiar with the word *shenanigans* than the word *grok*. But, after all, if I'm uncomfortable with the idea, this may not be the site for me. Also, `6,180,000` are hardly 6.5 **billions**.

Comment: @Dennis - not just US - those of us in other parts of the world that read Heinlien's Stranger in a Strange Land know what it means.

Comment: @ChrisF: That just just countering the it's-in-the-dictionary point. Oxford classifies *grok* as US only ([link](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/grok)).

Comment: (I know it's millions; I noticed my mistake too late to edit) 'grok' is less obscure than "understand", but no less so than "shenanigans". I use it all the time and have yet to meet someone who didn't understand it. More importantly, replacing it with "understanding" is not necessarily *clarifying*. There are lots of things I superficial understand but don't really *grok*; grok implies a fuller understanding, really *getting* something.

Comment: That's because you haven't met me. *More importantly, replacing it with "understanding" is not necessarily clarifying.* What's wrong with using *fully understand*, then? And since we're using Google hits to measure clarity: `grok: 6 million hits - shenanigans: 25 million hits - 1,350 million hits`

Comment: You've *never met someone who didn't understand "grok"*? Wow. Can't say I share that same experience... You know it was coined in 1961 by a science fiction author in the book *[Stranger in a Strange Land](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stranger_in_a_Strange_Land)*? Not everyone has read that book. For example, I haven't. The only way I know about it is someone used it once, forcing me to go look it up.

Comment: FWIW I think overuse of "grok", especially in the tense "grokking" *is* a bit annoying. I personally wouldn't edit it or leave that rev comment, but it is a little annoying. However, if I was the OP I'd probably roll it back - there's nothing wrong with having a little personality to your post, and this is obviously a style choice, grammar-wise, and totally valid.

Comment: I was going to edit out the word "stupid" until I realized that was the edit summary...

Comment: The word, at least in programming circles is not unusual. It has had an entry in the [hackers dictionary](http://www.outpost9.com/reference/jargon/jargon_22.html#SEC29) for many many years. As such, any self respecting geek programmer should know it.

Comment: @Oded: Can you please edit your comment? People just don't grok how stupid they sound when they say 'geek', it has to stop.

Comment: @WesleyMurch - I reserve my right to sound stupid and yours to parody an edit comment.

Comment: The user in question is proficient in [tag:perforce] and [tag:vb6], perhaps grok is not widely understood by that audience?

Comment: @sixlettervariables the implication there is really harsh, but nicely personifies Oded's no real scotsman argument well.

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter: it seemed like a perfectly cromulent observation given the tone of the comment. Besides, I thought real scotsmen were defined by what they didn't wear, not by how much they could grok.

Comment: @Wesley: It's interesting that you find "grok" annoying because its *overused*, which the editor in question did as well, while the *defense* of the edit (seen in this thread) is that the word is too obscure.

Comment: @Mud: "Obscure" and "overused" are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: I am more concerned about the revision comment than I am the edit itself. Fine, get rid of the word. I've personally never used it, have only once or twice heard it spoken, and have only read it, well, *here*. But that revision comment would raise my ire.

Comment: @The Extablishment: "someone used it once, forcing me to go look it up" Which is to say, you knew what it meant. And you learned it the same way you learned many other words in your vocabulary.

Comment: Yes, +1 for me. The point is it's not ubiquitous.

Comment: Also, "cromulent"? Another word I've never heard before. Had to look that one up, and I end up with "a humorous neologism coined by television writer David X. Cohen". Well, that's unhelpful... I didn't think it was very humorous.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: it reminds me of a [fun editor from 2011](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98149/162175).

Comment: @TheEstablishment: hopefully this experience will embiggen you to embrace popular, new vocabulary.

Comment: *I still don't know what the hell it means.* Stop breaking the English language. It was broken enough before you started.

Comment: @TheEstablishment The future is going to be painful for you.

Comment: @Oded apparently you're not alone in the sentiment "...any self respecting geek programmer should know it." [from Rick Chapman is In Search of Stupidity](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Stupidity.html)
*It never would have occurred to him to take technological leadership because he didn’t grok the technology; in fact, the very use of the word grok in that sentence would probably throw him off.* Of course you might not want to use this to back up your argument because that would be argumentum ad verecundiam.

Answer (score 18):

> Is it acceptable to rewrite someone's post just because you don't approve of their writing voice?

Yes, of course it is. So long as you're making it *more clear* what they're saying.

Changing the *meaning* of their posts is probably not a good idea.

And it's always good to refrain from excessively trivial edits. So while the one in question is less than stellar because it changes only a single word, that's not to suggest that rewriting jargon-laden or obtusely-worded sentences is a bad practice in general.

And remember, the user who made the edit has full editing privileges and their edits are not required to be peer reviewed. Thus, if they want to make trivial edits, that's their prerogative.

If this were a suggested edit that I saw in the queue, I would have undoubtedly voted to reject it as excessively trivial (which is different than rejecting it because it's *incorrect* or *invalid*).

> Grok is a [widely used word](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1_____enUS441US441&aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=grok) (especially in geek circles) 
>   and it's included in [several dictionaries](http://onelook.com/?w=grok).

Lots of "txtspk" can now be considered "widely used", probably more so than jargon like "grok". And those "words" are beginning to be included in dictionaries. For example, here's the same site showing the definitions for ["lol"](http://onelook.com/?w=lol&ls=a). That definition appears in at least as many dictionaries as "grok", and is definitely more universally understood by an Internet audience.

Of course, if someone had edited "lol" out of a post, no one would have gotten excited. You probably wouldn't even have posted this question. So what's the difference?

Comment: «Thus, if they want to make trivial edits, that's their prerogative.» But it is also the prerogative of other users to review such edits.

Comment: No, users with full edit privileges don't require their edits to be reviewed. Note that I didn't say someone's edits should be beyond question; I just see little questionable here.

Comment: @TheEstablishment: It comes into play when either making the decision to edit without privileges (should I edit this?) or when reviewing those edits (should I approve this?). In this case it wasn't relevant but it could be in others.

Comment: @Wesley: Yes, getting confused at what I've said in comments and what actually made it into my answer. Added that distinction in. I think it is an important one.

Comment: Edits being "reviewed" is one of two main goals, as I understand it, behind bumping posts to the front page. They aren't required to be _approved_, but keeping an eye on privileged edits from time to time (for those one or two that are _actually_ problematic) is one of the things that experienced members can do to contribute to site maintenance.

Comment: Yes. I'm not saying they should be beyond oversight. I never said that you should not question people's edits. Am I the one that's communicating this poorly? Feel free to edit my answer to make that more clear. The point is that there's a different standard for *triviality* when it comes to suggested edits than applies to users with full edit privileges. That say nothing about the *validity* of edits. **My point is that this one is not *invalid*, it's just *trivial*, but since he has full edit privileges, that's not a problem.**

Comment: If you can edit the word "lol" *out* of a sentence without changing it's meaning, then it was clearly fluff. This was changing the word in the middle of the sentence because the editor has a personal problem with the *color* of someone's language usage. It wasn't a superfluous word, it just *isn't the word the editor would have chosen*. It seems a rather capricious reading for editing someone's post (especially if you're then going to call them *stupid*).

Answer (score 15):

No, that's a terrible edit. If this little change were part of a larger grammatical cleanup of the post, that would be one thing, but ["grok" is in the dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/grok) (as you've pointed out) and widely understood by the audience here anyways, and there's no reason to change it.

The edit should probably be reverted.

For the wider question you've asked:

> Is it acceptable to rewrite someone's post just because you don't approve of their writing voice?

It depends on whether that voice makes the question difficult to understand or noisy. If a person's "voice" includes a lot of off-topic remarks, txtspk, lack of capitalization, weird formatting, or similar features that obscure the question, then, yes, edit that sucker.

Comment: If/when txtspk makes it into the dictionary, is using it okay? Because, the only dictionaries that "grok" has made it into make it very clear that it is slang. And "lol" has made it into several dictionaries now as slang.

Comment: @The An insightful question. I suppose it might be, but damned if I'm ever going to use it. Get off my grammar, you whippersnappers!

Comment: No, I'm not going to use it either. And I'm going to continue editing it out. The point was a larger one about jargon and slang not necessarily belonging in answers, and that there's nothing wrong with editing that stuff out. Sure, they probably should have made a more substantive edit at the same time, but it's not a "terrible" edit, and there's definitely no reason to revert it. I'm a native US English speaker, and I encounter the word "grok" about once a year. At best.

Comment: More seriously, I'd say the important issue is that this doesn't make the post unintelligible enough to justify editing only that word, just as a single "u"->"you" edit would be unjustified. I think we may disagree on that.

Comment: Indeed. Words need to be spelled out. When they're not, that's a grammatical problem and should be fixed. Diction is also grammatical. That said, standards are different for suggested edits than they are for those users with full editing privileges. I would have rejected this edit for being excessively trivial if I saw it in the suggested edits queue. But it didn't cost me anything for someone with full editing privileges to make it, so I don't see the harm. As long as it didn't *negatively* impact the meaning of the post, then there's no issue.

Comment: I'll concede the "should be reverted" point.

Comment: I've never heard of the word 'Grok' before, so personally think the edit would be fine. Oh, and whilst on the subject of [Grammar and slang](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10847/how-did-anyway-become-anyways-anyway), I'd have edited your answer if my rep allowed me to do so. :)

Comment: @Bryan: That's a pretty trivial edit to make, though I concede that _anyway_ is more strictly correct. My guess would be that the _s_ comes from speech, getting tacked on the same way many people (U.S.) say Daylight Saving_s_ Time -- it makes the spoken transition between phonemes/letters easier.

Answer (score 11):

I had no clue what that word meant and never heard it until I actually looked at the dictionary link you posted. So no, it's not as widespread as you think.

More importantly, in that particular case of "I'm having a hard time grokking classes in Lua", the context is not informative of the meaning of that word. Imagine that you saw:

> I'm having a hard time xjensing classes in Lua.

Would you have any idea what the question is trying to ask? I didn't think so.

(Possible context-aware verb candidates: inheriting, implementing, using, writing, reading, staring at, understanding, asking Stack Overflow questions about...)

If someone omitted the verb completely and said "I'm having a hard time with classes" there would be three insta-downvotes, and five comments saying "be more specific" and "what is your question?"

Raven's edit **adds value**, by making the question **much** clearer and is therefore appropriate in that case.

Comment: For a long time I didn't xjensing "grok", I thought it was a bash command or something. ^_^

Comment: You can frob his question repeatedly.

Comment: Put "I'm having a hard time xjensing classes in lua" back into its _full_ context and it becomes much easier to ken.

Comment: @JacquesCousteau Not at all. What follows is mostly a bunch of code. Replace the verb with "inheriting" for example. Changes the question completely.