# Warning about localhost prevents me from editing a question

Tags: discussion, bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The link validator is overzealous and should allow posting so-called 'invalid' links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134229/the-link-validator-is-overzealous-and-should-allow-posting-so-called-invalid-l)

I tried to edit a question which had some references to `http://localhost` in it. When trying to submit my chances I got the following error:

[image: localhost]

Besides the minor design "issue" in it (box is too wide) I think it is strange that OP has created a question what that in it, but that when I was editing I couldn't save it because it was in there.

Now that I think about it: do we really want to prevent people from adding some link with `http://localhost` in it? In this specific case it was just to give an example of an URL and it was not meant to be clicked. And when people do accidentally add a link to `localhost` they will find out soon enough.

See the revisions of the question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10363072/revisions. I had to make both links into a codeblock. As you can see OP got those links in his question without any problems (by the looks of it), but it started to bug me when I tried to submit the changes.