# Why are edits removing "Thanks in advance" sometimes rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I can't edit posts for a week because I deleted the text. "thanks in advance" from a number of posts. I read a lot about the topic on this site, and I don't think that it's fair.

People rejected the edits in review saying that it is not constructive. However, I read here that it is considered rude to say "thanks in advance" and that the best way to say thanks is to upvote the question.

If that is the case, then why do some people allow me to delete "thanks is advance" while others do not?

Comment: If you only removed thanks, and there was much else wrong with the post, that would by many be considered a too minor edit and rejected. (No idea whether that applies, haven't looked at your suggestions yet.)

Comment: I think most people don't see it as rude to say "thanks in advance".

Comment: @Pekka Agree. I guess it's a misconception based on [this previous post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98149/why-is-it-considered-rude-to-say-thanks-in-advance). I've never seen it as rude myself. Just unnecessary.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

All you did was remove `thanks` from posts, leaving other problems in place. Such edits are too minor and clog up the queue.

When making an edit suggestion, please improve the whole post, and not only remove the 'thank you'.

Generally, count on edit suggestions that only touch one small aspect to be rejected.  Note that the *too minor* rejection reason states this unequivocally:

> This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive
>   improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.

Users with editing rights (more than 2000 reputation) can edit "thanks" out without the hassle of the suggested edits queue. The point is that we don't want to burden the queue with small trivial edits and waste reviewers' time.

Comment: Why some people accept that edits and other not?It´s because they don´t read and they only wanted point per reviwing

Comment: There are a *lot* of people reviewing suggested edits. There are always people that are not familiar with the way we view such posts here yet, so sometimes such minor edits do get approved.

Comment: @Aitul maybe, but also because not everybody has the same opinion about what is a useful edit.

Comment: Everyone likes your answer but anyone likes my question...this is not fair

Comment: @Aitul: See the [meta-faq#vote-differences]; votes on MSO are different from the regular Stack Exchange websites.

Comment: @Aitul: Yeah, if you're doing a bunch of lazy, trivial edits something tells me it's not the reviewers who "don't read and only wanted points". If you're doing purely cosmetic edits, the post's grammar and style should be flawless when you're done with it. Otherwise, why are you bothering?

Comment: @Aitul It's the people who *do* accept trivial edits that are the problem.  The people who reject them are doing the right thing.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: I'm not a big fan of conflicting directives.  We should either categorically state that we don't want "Thanks in Advance" in questions and allow people to edit them out, or state that they're perfectly fine and reject the edits.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The past discussions have reached a consensus.  It's a valid edit to make, as a part of a larger edit, but on it shouldn't be the only edit that you make to a post.

Comment: @Servy: I'm not a big fan of that directive either.  There's more than one editor out there; this is supposed to be a collaborative effort.  I've seen that argument made with trivial spelling changes to, and that argument also sucks.  If it improves a post, it's a good edit.  That's it.  If you want to discourage suggested editors, rejecting such edits is a great way to accomplish that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm in favor of removing "thanks" from posts.  If that's all I can find wrong with a post, I'd accept the edit.  If the editor is leaving behind a lot of other things that need to be fixed, I'd reject it.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Isn't there an "accept and improve" button?

Comment: @RobertHarvey So you feel that "too minor" should be removed as a rejection reason for suggested edits?  It sounds like you're saying no edit is ever too minor.  Now, I won't demand that every edit always fix every single possible error, but I would hope that the editor *attempted* to fix every error.  They should have at least read the whole post and fixed every mistake that they could find.  If there is only one thing they could find them I could justify making a small change, and have, but when there are obvious and significant existing errors making small edits  can do more harm than good.

Comment: @Servy: If "Thanks in advance" is too minor to be removed, then it shouldn't be removed.  "Too minor" is for things like changing `flavour` to `flavor.`

Comment: @RobertHarvey To the point of improving, there are two problems.  First, would you mark the edit as helpful or not?  Personally, if I spend more time editing the post then I feel the editor needed I won't mark it helpful, otherwise I will.  Next, there is the issue of other reviewers reviewing a post out from under me when improving it, and finally there is the general concept that if you're taking time to suggest edits you shouldn't be generating substantially more work for the reviewers (who are actually doing most of the real editing) than you are doing yourself.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, but I don't always have time to revise an entire post just because someone removed "thanks" and did nothing else.

Comment: @RobertHarvey `flavour` isn't actually wrong, grammatically.  Changing it would be an invalid edit, not a "too minor" edit as it's not making it any more or less correct, it's just changing the "voice" of the post from one person's to another's.

Comment: @Servy: Perhaps I'm biased from my viewpoint as a moderator, but I don't grade the entire editing effort; I judge the edit on its own merit.  If the edit substantially improves the post, I approve it.  So it comes down to whether or not removing "Thanks in Advance" improves the post.  I don't expect folks to always make the effort cleaning up every spelling and grammatical error that a user makes posting a question from their cell phone, *because I don't.*  I'll tell the person to clean up their own post first.

Comment: @Servy: All that said, if a user is exhibiting a pattern of making no other edit to several posts, other than "Thanks in Advance," I might have a discussion with him to the effect of "This isn't really what editing is all about."  Putting "Thanks in Advance" on posts is an extremely popular practice; I remove them when I see them, but it's always going to be controversial for that reason.  Tying their removal to other edits is basically acknowledging that the issue really isn't all that important.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I believe that there is a category of edits that are "minor".  They include things like removing "thanks", signatures, introductions, individual spelling mistakes, etc.  Making a single minor edit as an entire edit is generally "too minor", and should be rejected.  When an edit contains a number of minor edits, or a minor edit as well as major edits, then the entire edit is not "too minor" and should be approved.  There is an entirely separate category of "invalid edits".  If an invalid edit is made the suggestion should be rejected, even if there are also valid major edits.

Comment: @Servy: How easy is this to explain to a new user or a reviewer?  Is it intuitive, or counter-intuitive, to have an edit which clearly has community support to be rejected because it is too minor?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Do you have an alternate definition of "too minor" that you feel is better?  As it is there is virtually no "training" or formal guidelines for reviewing suggested edits, which I feel is a *major* problem with the system.  This thread is one of many problems that result from that lack of formal and easily found information.

Comment: @Servy: Which is why I'm inclined to give suggested editors the benefit of the doubt, if they're not causing genuine harm.  I don't have an answer for the training problem, other than to say that the system should be as "self-describing" as possible.  People shouldn't have to go through these kinds of mental convolutions to make a useful edit, though I do think people should make a good faith effort to be good editors.  If that means that some of their edits get rejected and they have to come here for clarification, so be it, I guess.

Comment: @Servy: You should put your definition of too minor (less than two "minor" edits) in its own answer. :)  Or maybe reference some of the previous meta posts that define and clarify this notion of "too minor."  Maybe we can get this information into a [meta-tag:faq] entry.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I feel that the answer answers the question, our discussion is really going off on a tangent.  I'd post a new question, but I'm reasonably sure there are already questions discussing what "too minor" is, so it's end up closed as a duplicate of something.  I'm still curious what your definition of "too minor" is though, you didn't answer that question.

Comment: @Servy "Too minor" is an edit that doesn't substantially improve the post.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That seems to conflict with the sub-text: `This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.`

Comment: @Servy: Ah, meah culpa.  Well, there it is.  I guess if there is only one thing wrong with a post, it gets to stay in the post.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: But 2K+ users can edit it out without the hassle of the suggested edits queue. The point is that we don't want to burden the queue with small trivial edits and waste reviewers time.

Comment: I'm against giving editors the benefit of the doubt. "Fixing" posts by looking for some consensus on Meta (in this case: remove "thanks"), and then cargo-cultishly editing your way to 2k rep by enforcing that consensus *while ignoring the real quality issues in a post* feels wrong. It is bound to frustrate good suggested editors who actually put time and effort in fixing stuff while getting the same +2 for their work.

Comment: @Pekka: I'm coming around to the idea that clipping "thanks" out of posts with suggested edits, but doing nothing else, is just gaming the system.

Comment: @Pekka: Then maybe the problem is that suggested edits get rep. Maybe they shouldn't. Or maybe there should be a way to say "It's a solid edit, but not worthy of rep."

Comment: @NicolBolas If reviewers rejected minor edits then it wouldn't be a problem.  Rather than fixing what editor suggest you first need to fix what reviewers approve.  If serial minor edits just resulted in all being rejected, then no rep would be earned and the user would be blocked from suggesting edits.

Comment: @Servy: Not all reviewers agree with the minor edits policy. Indeed, not all reviewers are *aware* of the minor edits policy. And forcing them to adhere to this policy isn't a good idea either.

Comment: If the people suggesting edits know what is acceptable, and edit accordingly, but the people reviewing edits don't, and don't review appropriately, then why do we have a review system in the first place?  The entire purpose of the review system is so that suggesters *don't* need to know all of the rules, their suggestions will just be rejected when they're wrong, allowing them to learn as they go through feedback.  If you just assume reviewers won't even know how to review properly you may as well remove the entire functionality and only let 2k+ users edit posts.

Comment: @Servy: It's 2K+ users who are approving the suggested edits. :/

Comment: @RobertHarvey A *lot* of people end up accepting edits that they themselves wouldn't make.  Even I do that, I just make sure the edit is appropriate before doing so, unlike certain others.  Reviewing really is harder than actually editing yourself, at least in my experience.