# What is the etiquette for adding a "signature" to a question?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed)

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298568/winforms-what-is-the-simplest-way-to-update-a-property-in-thread-safe-manner) and at the end I put the following:

> Can anyone help with this?
>
> Thanks
>
> Keith

The question then got edited and the text removed with the comment of "removing signiture". I wouldn't consider that a signature, just politeness, and have done that or something similar for all my questions.

As I don't have a high enough rep I can't edit without peer revenue and would not expect a similar edit to be passed. Whereas the editor does have high enough reputation so was able to edit as they saw fit.

Is it right the signature was removed and I shouldn't put such text on my future questions?

Comment: To answer your question in comments here - yes it is right - your box on the right is your signature. When you get over a certain level of rep you get a hovercard too :)

Comment: @Diago now I've read the linked question I understand. I wouldn't think its a tagline or a signature but it is extra text (noise) that doesn't clarify the question.

Comment: Every question I read I assume there's an implicit "thanks for taking the time", unless the question itself is just "plz send teh codez" in which case no amount of "thanks" could fix it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Such signatures are considered noise. They don't add *anything* to the question.

We see the questions and answers as the value of StackExchange sites, so anything that detracts from that is discouraged.

This includes signatures, salutations (hi there, hello, this is my first post, etc...) and thanks/names at the end of the post.

It is not that they are not allowed, but that the community doesn't see a benefit in them, so they get removed.

Comment: Plus, every post has your username already attached to it, you don't need to add your name again.