# Is it good or bad style to ask for help?

Tags: discussion

I wonder whether I should end a question on SO with a polite phrase asking or thanking in advance for help, such as:

- “Any help is apreciated.”
- “Thanks in advance for any help.”
- “Any advice on how to tackle this?”

Or should I let that be and just type in my question? Is there consensus on this topic or a policy I did’t find yet?

When editing ugly questions (bad markup, or typos), should I add or remove such a phrase at the end?

Comment: We've got a few posts that hit on this, actually: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) and [Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed) for example. Note that "thanks" is generally lumped in with signatures around here. Signatures and taglines are also mentioned in [the help center.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)

Comment: No policy, but surely a consensus saying that it's not OK to have those things. (known as salutations)

Comment: phrases like this add no information. You don't really want "any help" - people commenting on your naming conventions in a code question, advice to take an umbrella when it's raining, a handy recipe for lemon bars - you want something specific. Ask for that. Be as specific as you can, you'll make your question better.