# stackoverflow answers on twitter

Tags: support, twitter

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Broadcasting User-Activity over Twitter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2585/broadcasting-user-activity-over-twitter)
>   [Why isn’t SuperUser on twitter?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15110/why-isnt-superuser-on-twitter)

How can I associate my questions/answers with my Twitter account so my questions and answers are automatically posted on twitter?

Comment: Do all your questions/answers have only 144 characters? :-P

Comment: Should be on meta.stackoverflow.com...

Comment: Dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2585/broadcasting-user-activity-over-twitter http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15110/why-isnt-superuser-on-twitter

Answer (score 4):

### No

Nor you should.

If you feel strongly about it, you could build it yourself once the Stack Overflow API becomes public.

Comment: http://twitter.com/isnotrss