# Social media sharing of my activity

Tags: feature-request, facebook, social-networking, twitter, integration

Users want to share my activities here on StackOverflow on their facebook twitter etc.. 
e.g "I have earned this badge" or "I have answered this question on StackOverflow" etc.

I am a mobile application developer, I can also work on this module if there is some one who can direct me in the right way.

Comment: Think this has already been asked: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2585/154443

Comment: i tried searching previously but couldnt find it, well but that request is more centric on twitter while i am talking of a more generic one

Answer (score 2):

You can develop your own social media sharing plugin using the api:

[API Documentation and Help](https://stackapps.com/questions/1/api-documentation-and-help)

You will have to host it yourself, and set up your own triggers or schedule, but it should be easy to do.

Also check out the existing apps to see if one or a combination of several might accomplish your goal already:

https://stackapps.com/