# Can the SE sites tweet me when someone comments or answers my question?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, twitter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Broadcasting User-Activity over Twitter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2585/broadcasting-user-activity-over-twitter)

If I use the tweet functionality of the SE range of sites, can you please tweet me if someone comments or answers one of my questions. Or, comments on an answer ?

Comment: Why? What's wrong with all of the existing notification mechanisms? The ones on the site work just fine, and if necessary, you can request to be e-mailed this information.

Comment: Check out [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2585/162705) and [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2585/broadcasting-user-activity-over-twitter/2618#2618). Besides, if [Jon Skeet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) thinks ["it has problems"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2585/broadcasting-user-activity-over-twitter/2587#2587), you probably wouldn't want it anyway. :)

Comment: Right; one of the primary issues is that it doesn't scale. Imagine if you were an active contributor to the site like Jon Skeet or [many others](http://stackoverflow.com/users). You wouldn't want all of this being twitted. That's one of the reasons why email is consolidated and only sent around once a day. We don't want to overwhelm your inbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not the intended function of the Twitter bots.

It'd also be technically complicated, as [DM's are constrained](http://support.twitter.com/entries/14606-what-is-a-direct-message-dm) and generic @tweets would be really sucky for anyone *not you* following the bots.