# Send reponse on mobile phones like facebook

Tags: feature-request, responses

I would like to have this feature with stack overflow. Send response(answers and comments) on registered mobile phones. It would be up-to user to receive response on mobile or not.

Sometimes don't understand any response is received while posting question or commenting and answering question. We have to keep eye on it.

It would be great to have this feature like facebook to receive response on mobile.

(Or also we can have responses for selected question which we want to receive on mobile,
or receive one day later responses on mobile)

Comment: Stackdroid from stack apps pretty much does that I think.

Comment: @awoodland: I didn't understand more about Stackdroid? Can you give more about it?

Comment: http://stackapps.com/questions/585/droidstack-for-android-now-with-chat-support

Comment: And please I am not saying it should be compulsory. It should be upto user who wanted to addict of it. (Like facebook addicted users want to receive comments when they are offline)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**We already have this.** There's [a beautifully-designed mobile site theme](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/mobile-stack-exchange/) available for most if not all of the common phones (also see [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81370/new-stack-overflow-mobile-site) and [the original feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896/mobile-and-iphone-optimized-version-of-stack-overflow)).

The developers really put a lot of love into this. It supports nearly everything that the full site does, all on a small screen and optimized for *speed* on slow connections. You can read all of the content, post questions/answers, vote on posts, view and leave comments, receive comment and other notifications, and even perform some moderation tasks like casting close/delete votes on questions (assuming, of course, that you have the requisite privileges).

If you have additional feedback for the mobile site, or you happen to have a device that has not been whitelisted to receive the mobile theme, suggest it by posting an answer to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98776/stack-exchange-mobile-launched).

If that's not good enough for you (*sheesh!*) and you were expecting Stack Exchange to constantly ping your phone with text messages, then I'm afraid you might be out of luck. I suspect the overwhelming majority of users would *never* want that. If you absolutely need to get more jingle from Stack Overflow, consider creating and subscribing to a [Twitter-as-RSS feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2585/broadcasting-user-activity-over-twitter). (Also see: [Can the SE sites tweet me when someone comments or answers my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100787/can-the-se-sites-tweet-me-when-someone-comments-or-answers-my-question))

Comment: You are explaining all about what mobile features SO gives. **We already have this.** I couldn't see messaging system of SO. Only last para's first 2 lines gives your opinion. And I said there should be functionality 'for selected question which we want to receive on mobile'. And How could you afraid I might be out of luck, if Stack Exchange to constantly ping my phone with text messages.

Comment: @Som: The messaging system is in the upper right-hand corner of the mobile site—just like on the main site, you'll see a red circle with a number in it if you have any messages. If you want to read questions on your mobile phone, you can already do that.

Comment: Yes. It is great functionality. But am I able to receive messages of responses given to my posts?

Comment: @Somnath - That's the global inbox, it includes comments on your posts and answers to your questions, yes.  It's the same inbox as in the upper left corner of every site that you see now.